# Dynamically change the URL of Yii ajaxLink on success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

How can I change the URL parameter of an ajax link after the ajax has successfully executed?  The following code doesn't work, but explains what I want to do.

```php
CHtml::ajaxLink($text, array('/core/bookmark/create'), array(
    'data' => array("id" => $id),
    'type' => 'GET',
    'success'=>'js:function(data){
        if (data.status == "success"){ 
            //attempt to dynamically change the URL
            this.url = "/core/bookmark/delete";
            $("#bookmark-btn").toggleClass("bookmark_on").toggleClass("bookmark_off");
        }
    }',
), array('id'=>'bookmark-btn', 'class' => 'bookmark_off'));
```

the line with `this.url` makes no effect on the ajaxLink's URL, but it doesn't throw any errors in the console either.

Comment: you can't do this but call another ajax call after success

Comment: @GBD Can you give me an example? Note, I don't want to execute the  other ajax call on success - I just want to change the URL on this ajax call (for the next time the user clicks).  To make sense of this, what I am trying to do is implement a bookmark button which toggles between `add` and `delete` functionality on each click.

Comment: Whats the use case for this? may be there is a better solution

Comment: @Asgaroth (1) Display a link (that looks like an icon) allowing user to bookmark content. (2) User clicks the link, it creates a Bookmark model record. (3) The link visually updates the icon by changing its class. Now when the user clicks on the link, it will Delete the bookmark model previously created. (4) It should alternate between create/delete on every click.

Comment: @Adamski looks like it should be done in the backend, like, have the same url and the logic there will validate what action it should take. the visual difference can be accomplished by just changing the CSS class for example

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd render both the `add` and `delete` links, and just toggle the visibility of each as needed.

Comment: @Asgaroth You're right. It does have some limitations this way, but it's the easiest route to go. Ernie you're also right, but in this instance the other method suits me better.

Answer (score 2):

`CHtml::ajaxLink` renders `a` element, which doesnt have `url` attribute. You need such code:

```
if (data.status == "success"){ 
    jQuery(this).attr('href', '/core/bookmark/delete');
}
```

**Update:**

> Besides, what I'm wanting to do is change the URL in the Ajax function which fires when the link is clicked, not on the link itself.

In that case, better solution is to draw two `CHtml::ajaxLink` elements and toggle the visibility of them according to ajax-requests result. It will cost you less effort.

Comment: I don't think that's correct in this case... If I look at my DOM on the page load: `href="#"`  ... Using your line does not change the `href` attribute on success (but I am sure it's firing). Besides, what I'm wanting to do is change the URL in the Ajax function which fires when the link is clicked, not on the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your current approach is twofold:

1. the .url property refers to the documents URL, not the link's URL
2. what you really want to change is the action performed in the
   event handler in the javascript, not a part of the DOM

I think to get the behavior you want, you'll need to handle this in your controller, as well as modifying your ajaxLink a bit to keep track of state.

```
CHtml::ajaxLink($text, array('/core/bookmark/create'), array(
    'data' => array("id" => $id, "state"=>$("#bookmark-btn").hasClass("bookmark_on") ),
    'type' => 'GET',
    'success'=>'js:function(data){
        if (data.status == "success"){ 
            var bookmarkState = $("#bookmark-btn").hasClass("bookmark_on");
            if (!bookmarkState) {
                $("#bookmark-btn").addClass("bookmark_on").removeClass("bookmark_off");
                // Probably need some code here to update the link text as well
            } else {
                $("#bookmark-btn").addClass("bookmark_off").removeClass("bookmark_on");
                // Probably need some code here to update the link text as well
            }
        }
    }',
), array('id'=>'bookmark-btn', 'class' => 'bookmark_off'));
```

Then, in your controller (which I'd probably rename from `create` to something more generic like `handleBookmark`), you'd need to check the value of `state`, and then call the existing `create` or `delete` actions that you've already written.

Alternatively, you could do this on the client side via jQuery, but you'd have to write custom triggers and actions (most likely reading the value of the `$("#bookmark-btn")`, and going down different javascript paths there).  This would mean you'd need to write your javascript directly, rather than using the Yii `ajaxLink` convenience method.

As has been noted, the easier way of doing this is probably to render both an `add` and `delete` link and toggle the visibility as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You're right that the best way to achieve this is in my controller logic.  Probably also, I can return the new text for the Bookmark in the `data` JSON object returned by server. I don't see the need for your if/else block - I can simply send the new link text back from the server and apply it. From what I can gather, the statements `$("#bookmark-btn").toggleClass("bookmark_on").toggleClass("bookmark_off");` and `$("#bookmark-btn").toggleClass("bookmark_off").toggleClass("bookmark_on");` are equivalent. So the if/else is completely redundant.

Comment: @Adamski Ah, wasn't paying attention with the if-then . . . what it should have been is `addClass()` and `removeClass` calls to explicitly set them, rather than toggling.  Updated.  You're right that passing it via the controller would work as well, and just set the text of the element that way.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why your method does not work

The actual reason this is not working is that you are changing the *current* jquery ajax object's url property, and not the url for future objects. This becomes obvious when you see the generated html/js:

Link:

```
<a href="#" class="bookmark_off" id="bookmark-btn">value-of-text</a>
```

Event listener (the following is found usually in the last `<script>` before `</body>` , i have also added a few comments):

```
$('body').on('click','#bookmark-btn',function(){
    jQuery.ajax({'data':{'id':1},'type':'GET',
        'success':js:function(data){
            if (data.status == "success"){
                //attempt to dynamically change the URL
                this.url = "/core/bookmark/delete";
                $("#bookmark-btn").toggleClass("bookmark_on").toggleClass("bookmark_off");
            }
        },
        'url':'/project-name/index.php/core/bookmark/create', // this url is used repeatedly
        'cache':false
    }); // ajax call ends
    return false; // click handler ends
});
```

The above listener shows that for each click a **new** ajax object/call is created/done, therefore everytime only *that* object's url is changed, but not for the **next** object, which will be created for the next call. For the next call the same old url will be used, i.e : `'url':'/project-name/index.php/core/bookmark/create',` .

---

#### Solution

There is a way to "dynamically change the url of an ajax link". Instead of using `CHtml::ajaxLink`, use a [normal `CHtml::link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail), but with added [`clientChange` options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail). The `clientChange` options are included within the third parameter to `CHtml::link`, i.e within `htmlOptions`. This way we can specify a dynamic url for ajax calls, which will use the `href` of the `<a>` tag generated for ajax calls, instead of a static url.

An example (read the comments in code):

```
echo CHtml::link($text, array('/core/bookmark/create'), array(
    // the htmlOptions array, with clientOptions included
    'id'=>'bookmark-btn',
    'class' => 'bookmark_off',
    'return' => false, // this is already false by default - read documentation
    'ajax' => array( // now specify the ajax options, with a dynamic url
        'url' => 'js:$(this).attr("href")', // this takes the href property of
                // the <a> tag that is generated for this CHtml::link
        'data' => array('id' => $id),
        'custom_data_passed_to_ajax_object' => 'js:this', // this is important,
                // here we pass link, <a> tag, for use within the ajax object
        'success'=>'function(data){
            if (data.status == "success"){ 
                // now change the href of the <a> we passed in custom_data_passed_to_ajax_object
                $(this.custom_data_passed_to_ajax_object).attr("href",
                    "'.$this->createUrl('/core/bookmark/delete').'");
                $("#bookmark-btn").toggleClass("bookmark_on").toggleClass("bookmark_off");
            }
        }'
    )
));
```

You can actually adapt the above solution for `ajaxLink` also:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink($text,
    'js:$(this).attr("href")', // this will be generated as 'url':$(this).attr("href")
    array(// ajax options, remember to pass the reference to the <a>,
        // i.e custom_data_passed_to_ajax_object in the above snippet
    ),
    array(
        'href'=>$this->createUrl('/core/bookmark/create'), // your actual url
        // rest of htmlOptions
    )
);
```

---

As for your final goal of "implement a bookmark button which toggles between add and delete functionality on each click", everyone else has already given you enough hints to go on.

Comment: the other answers did not correctly identify the problem with the current code (imho), therefore this answer. be sure to ask for clarifications if needed. tried, but couldn't shorten the answer :)